# Анимация на SVG

Tags: css, svg, svg-animation

Помогите с созданием анимационной svg.

Пример анимации: https://codepen.io/supah/pen/BjYLdW

Долго искал, пытался но ничего не выходит. Есть готовая svg

```
.ub-spinner {     
    position: absolute;     
    left: 50%;     
    top: 50%;     
    width: clamp(50px, 15%, 200px);
    fill: #fff; 
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}

<svg viewBox="0 0 128 128" class="ub-spinner">
    <g>
        <path d="M64 9.75A54.25 54.25 0 0 0 9.75 64H0a64 64 0 0 1 128 0h-9.75A54.25 54.25 0 0 0 64 9.75z"></path>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 64 64" to="360 64 64" dur="1200ms" repeatCount="indefinite"></animateTransform>
     </g>
 </svg>
```

Пытался редактировать, но как всегда все криво на выходе.

Как сделать чтобы viewBox="0 0 36 36"

Было бы потрясающе, если удалось выполнить анимацию на svg такую же как в примере по ссылке

Целый день просидел, ну не выходит. Подскажите пожалуйста, каким редактором вы пользуетесь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо дуги можно использовать  `circle`, у которой с помощью анимации `stroke-dasharray` вырезать сегменты, а с помощью анимации `animateTransform` одновременно вращать окружность с вырезанными сегментами.
Как-то так:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-105deg, #009acc, #363795);
}
  
   .path {
     fill:none;
    stroke: #C1CFDB;
    stroke-width:3;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-dashoffset:100.5;
    stroke-dasharray:100.5; 
    animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
   
  }
  @keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0, 100;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 65, 35;
    stroke-dashoffset: -35;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 65, 100;
    stroke-dashoffset: -100.5;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="spinner" width="72" height="72" viewBox="0 0 36 36">
  <circle class="path" cx="18" cy="18" r="16" >
  <animateTransform  attributeName="transform" type="rotate"  dur="6s" values="0 18 18;360 18 18" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  </circle>
</svg>
```

### Решение SMIL

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-105deg, #009acc, #363795);
}
.container {
width:10vw;
height:10vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg class="spinner" viewBox="0 0 36 36">
  <circle class="path" cx="18" cy="18" r="16" fill="none" stroke="#C1CFDB" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dashoffset="100.5"  stroke-dasharray="100.5">
  <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="1.5s" values="0,100;65,35;65,100" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
   <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="1.5s" values="0;-35;-100.5" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  <animateTransform  attributeName="transform" type="rotate"  dur="6s" values="0 18 18;360 18 18" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  </circle>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: анимацию dash можно перенести в svg, а так просто копипаста с другими размерами ;)

Comment: @eri Ты думаешь для меня проблема написать анимацию в smil?

Comment: Подскажите, какими редакторами пользуетесь?

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов любой текстовый редактор подойдет, где есть подсветка синтаксиса XML Я использую Notepad++

Comment: @Alexandr_TT даже мысли такой не было)

Comment: Я думал, что применяю графические редакторы. Использую Inkscape, но он не поддерживает анимацию...

Comment: А через текстовые редакторы править, ну блин, сума сойти можно... Это невозможно, только если простенькие какие нибудь svg

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов согласен, это неудобно. Но ни каких других инструментов нет, которые бы подсказывали как правильно, какие команды использовать, какой синтаксис нужен. Насчет анимации тоже проблема, но их видов немного, всего четыре вида анимаций. Есть смысл написать для себя шпаргалку (образцы) и подставлять свои параметры. По крайне мере я так делал, когда начинал изучать SVG. Со временем будете их на  память писать. Кстати, почему не принимаете ответ? Что-то не так? Выберите ответ, который вам подошёл лучше всего и поставьте галку, чтобы вопрос не болтался открытым

Answer (score 2):

Чтоб сделать viewBox="0 0 36 36" нужно уменьшить размер кривой или будет видно только четверть рисунка. Если же надо уменьшить сам рисунок, то проще задать ширину в css вместо clamp.

Длинна арки анимируется как длинна штриха контура круга.
То что анимация `stroke-dasharray` не кладется на вашу арку - это из-за того что она оконтурена. Чтоб вcё исправить надо нарисовать новый рисунок по сути.

```
<svg class="spinner" viewBox="0 0 36 36">
  <circle class="path" cx="18" cy="18" r="16" fill="none" stroke-width="4"></circle>
</svg>
```

Или если хочется крутить арку, то она должна быть не оконтурена чтоб осталось что анимировать.

```
M 2,18 C 2,9 9,2 18,2 27,2 34,9 34,18
```

Арка конечно у меня получилась кривовата... Но если не приглядываться - не заметно

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #333
}
.ub-spinner {     
    position: absolute;     
    left: 50%;     
    top: 50%;     
    width: clamp(50px, 15%, 200px);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="ub-spinner">
    <g>
      <path d="M 2,18 C 2,9 9,2 18,2 27,2 34,9 34,18" stroke-dasharray="52 52" fill="none"  stroke="white">
          <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="2 52; 52 52;2 52" dur="2000ms" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </path>
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 18 18" to="360 18 18" dur="1500ms" repeatCount="indefinite"></animateTransform>
     </g>
 </svg>
```

Также как в примере с кругом можно бы добавить stroke-dashoffset анимацию, но она не будет красивой так как арка из path в отличие от круга не замкнута.

Comment: Надеюсь будет без обид,, поправил немного

Comment: полуслепой метод  печати)